# How to control the for loop layer numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I am a starter of Python and pretty interested in scripting with Python.

Recently, I faced a situation that I need to obtain all integer combination in the range of [-10, +10] and put them into two arrays in order, which means I have arrays [A] and [B], in [A], I need to have the first element to be [-10], the second [-10], and then in [B] it is [-10,-10], then I will erase the elements and make [A] have [-10,-10] but [B] have [-10, -9], then the next one is [A] = [-10,-10], [B] = [-10,-8]... until the last one [A] = [10,10], [B] = [10,10]. So I made 4-layer for loop to achieve that:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((1,2))
B = np.zeros((1,2))
for i in range(-10,+10+1):
    A[0][0] = I
    for ii in range(-10,+10+1):
        A[0][1] = ii
        for iii in range(-10,+10+1):
            B[0][0] = iii
            for iV in range(-10,+10+1):
                B[0][1] = iV
```

It works well to generate [A] and [B] in order in a stupid way. However, if I would like to change the size of [A] and [B], like A = np.zeros((1,3)), what should I do instead of adding more for loop lines? Is there a function to control the for loop numbers with different layers?

Thank you so much. Hope I have made my question clear LOL.

Best

Enxiao

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the `itertools` library:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
for combination in combinations_with_replacement(range(-10,11), n): # n being 4 in your case
    A[0] = combination[:n//2]
    B[0] = combination[n//2:]
```

The `combinations_with_replacement` generates tuples of `n` numbers in all combinations possible with the given numbers (range from -10 to 10); this can be split in two halves (`[:n//2]` -> first half, `[n//2:]` -> second half) and assigned to your array.

Comment: Hi Lukor, thanks so much for your help. The combinations_with_replaement looks pretty straightforward and simple. I run the code as you provided, but it seems that there is a tiny issue inside of it, namely, [A] and [B] are the same in each run (I reduced the range from  [-10,+10] to [-1,+1]): 
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EnxiaoLuan/Pics_for_Github/master/Annotation%202020-07-23%20145915.png" width="100" height="100">, is there anyway to improve that? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @EnxiaoLuan sorry for the late response; like I said in my answer: use 4 instead of 2 for n to get 4 numbers: 2 numbers for A and two numbers for B. Then, split them up using [:n//2] and [n//2:]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself without using `itertools` you can implement it like this:

```
import numpy as np

minVal, maxVal = -10, 10
sizeA, sizeB = 2, 2
totSize = sizeA+sizeB
AB = minVal * np.ones((totSize,))
while True:
    stop = True
    for i in range(totSize-1,-1,-1):
        if AB[i]<maxVal:
            AB[i] += 1
            AB[i+1:] = minVal
            stop = False
            break
    if stop:
        break

    A = AB[0:sizeA].reshape(1,-1)
    B = AB[sizeA:].reshape(1,-1)

    # Use A, B here
    print(A,B)
```

Comment: Hi Enxiao. No problem and welcome to SO. I saw you said that you were interested in scripting that's why I posted it. But [Lukor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63028499/6683322) is to be used if you are not interested in the specific implementation of this iterator.